# How to Pass Parameter to external class method?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to do very simple operation.

in "TestFile.h" file i've declare property:

```
@property (nonatomic) NSDictionary *justTest;
```

and in implementation file "TestFile.m":

```
-(NSDictionary *)justTest:(NSString *) mystring {

NSLog(@"Here is my string: %@", mystring);
return nil;
```

}

Now i am trying to call "justTest" from another file. What i am doing:

```
 #import "TestFile.h"


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.

  NSDictionary *testFile = [[TestFile alloc] init];

  [testFile justTest:@"Hello World!"]

}
```

This works fine until i'm trying to pass parameter.

if i just execute

```
[testFile justTest];
```

it works, but when i try to pass parameter

```
[testFile justTest:@"Hello World!"];
```

does not work and the debug message is:

```
no visible @interface for 'TestFile' declares the selector 'justTest':
```

What is wrong with me?

Comment: Note that what `[testFile justTest];` is really doing is getting the existing value of the property and then throwing it away.

Comment: [self justTest:@"Hello World!"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make this method public by adding method name to TestFile.h file before @end:

`-(NSDictionary *)justTest:(NSString *) mystring;`

Just to let you know when you add @property compiler synthesise it (create) two method getter, exactly the same name as your property and setter compiler add 'set' prefix, for example, you declare:

```
@property (nonatomic) NSDictionary *justTest;
```

compiler will create two methods:

```
-(NSDictionary *)justTest {...}
-(void)setJustTest {...}
```

You need to know that in your code you override the getter method.

Answer (score 1):

Declare your method in TestFile.h file before calling from an external class.

```
-(NSDictionary *)justTest:(NSString *) mystring;
```